# show that the integral is finite

Tags: fourier-series, fourier-transform

Let $f$ be piecewise-smooth and continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f,f'\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$. I want to show that

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (1+\vert x\vert^2)\vert \hat{f}(x)\vert^2 dx<\infty$$

Where $\hat{f}$ is the Fourier transform of $f$. Since $f,f'\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$, we have $\Vert f\Vert_{L^2} = \Vert \hat{f}\Vert_{L^2}$ and $\Vert f'\Vert_{L^2} = \Vert \hat{f'}\Vert_{L^2}$. Thus

\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (1+\vert x\vert^2)\vert \hat{f}(x)\vert^2 dx &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \vert \hat{f}(x)\vert^2 dx + \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \vert x\hat{f}(x)\vert^2 dx\\
&= \Vert \hat{f}\Vert_{L^2} + \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \vert x\hat{f}(x)\vert^2 dx\\
&= \Vert f\Vert_{L^2} + \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \vert x\hat{f}(x)\vert^2 dx.\\
\end{align*}

Now how do I evaluate the other integral? I'm sure I have to use $\Vert f'\Vert_{L^2} = \Vert \hat{f'}\Vert_{L^2}$ but i have no idea how. Any hints? I've been stuck for days now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Integrate by part to get
$$\hat {f'}(\xi)=\int_{\mathbb R}f'(x)e^{-2\pi i\xi x}dx=\underbrace{\left.f(x)e^{2\pi i\xi x}\right|_{-\infty}^{\infty}}_{=0}+2\pi i\xi\int_{\mathbb R}f(x)e^{-2\pi i\xi x}dx=2\pi i\xi\hat f(\xi)$$
therefore $\int_{\mathbb R}|\xi\hat {f'}(\xi)|^2d\xi$ is, up to a constant, $\|f'\|_{L^2}^2$

Comment: Why does the first term on the RHS go to 0?

Comment: f(x) is an $L^2$ function, it has to vanish at infinity

Comment: right, there are some delicacies here, but strictly speaking, the integral formula of the Fourier transform is defined for $L^1$ functions only, and one should not even try to use it for arbitrary $L^2$ functions in the first place. The typical way of defining Fourier transform is to define it for the Schwartz class using the integral formula, and extend it to tempered distributions by duality. The integration by part trick works for the Schwartz class, and then one can get the same property for distributional derivatives by duality.